# Regular expressions - Excel - Get matched value

Tags: microsoft-excel, regex

I'm looking for some advice.

I’m trying to use regular expresions in the Visual Basic for Excel (reference to Microsfot VBScript Regular Expresions 5.5 already set).

I just want this function to test my regex `\d\d\d\d\d` (to look for any 5 consecutive integers) and if it’s true, to give the matched value.

For instance, if I have the string “aaaaa 12345 bbb” I want the function to give “12345”. Seems easy but… not for me.

This is my code so far:

```
Function EXTRACT_CP(cell_with_text As Range) As String

Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strexpresion As String
Dim strInput As String
Dim strReplace As String
Dim strOutput As String

strexpresion = "\d\d\d\d\d"
strInput = UCase(cel_with_text.Value)

  regEx.Pattern = strexpresion

  If regEx.Test(strInput) Then

‘THIS LINE OBVIOUSLY FAILS BUT I DON’T KNOW WHAT TO PUT
        strOutput = regEx.Replace(strInput, "\d\d\d\d\d")

  End If

EXTRACT_CP = strOutput

End Function
```

Just want to know how to get the matched value for any regex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7087145/5494004

Answer (score 1):

Five consecutive digits?

Add variables:

```
Dim colMatches As Object
Dim ix As Long
Dim separator As String
```

A valid RegEx:

```
regEx.Pattern = "(\d{5})"
```

Change:

```
strOutput = regEx.Replace(strInput, "\d\d\d\d\d")
```

to:

```
Set colMatches = regEx.Execute(strInput)
```

and iterate your only match `(\d{5})` ~ `colMatches.Item(0)` for submatches:

```
separator = "|"
strOutput = ""
For ix = 0 to colMatches.Item(0).submatches.count - 1
  strOutput = strOutput + colMatches.Item(0).submatches.Item(ix) + separator
```

*Code is written without a VBA editor so adjustments might be needed.*